# bootstrap sidebar and content width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

i'm a beginner in creating responsive template and i want to create a layout with bootstrap application like this site http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0F35928

the main div would be sidebar and content div which looks like the site i've stated above,

the problem is  when i applied it on my own page, the responsive part does not function, it's just like a normal not responsive template. I already have all the js requirements for a responsive template yet it still does not work.

here's my html code:

```
 <div class="sidebar">
  <ul style="background:#aaa; margin-left:0 !important;">
    <li>list1</li>
    <li>list2</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid"> 
      This is a sample content
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.sidebar{
display:block;
 }
.sidebar > ul{
margin:10px 0 0;
padding:0;
position:absolute;
width:220px;
}
.content{
margin-right:0;
margin-left:220px;
min-height:740px;
padding-bottom:0 !important;
position:relative;
width:auto;
background:#fff;
}
```

in bootstrap-responsive.css I put this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
 .content{
   margin-left:0 !important;
 }
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
 .sidebar{
   float:none;
   width:100%;
  }
 .sidebar > ul{
   width:100%;
   position:relative;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For twitter bootstrap to be responsive, you must use the not only the bootstrap JS and css files, but you must also use the responsive css file as shown below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/AgTracker/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/AgTracker/resources/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css"/>
```

Are you using these two files?  Refer to [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) for more details.